# Extracting specific tags values with Apache Nutch

Tags: apache, web-scraping, html-parsing, nutch

I'm trying to fetch a list of several URLs and parse their title keywords and description (and ignore all the rest) using Apache Nutch
After that I just want to save for each URL all the title, keywords and description content (preferably without the tags themselves) without any indexing

I looked at several examples on how to this. Just a few examples of what I encountered:

- [How to parse content located in specific HTML tags using nutch plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972582/how-to-parse-content-located-in-specific-html-tags-using-nutch-plugin)
- http://www.atlantbh.com/precise-data-extraction-with-apache-nutch/

However they all propose complicated (at least to a Nutch newbie) plugins configuration and settings
Since my use case sounds like a very common one I was wondering if there is any simpler solution?

Thanks

Comment: I would like to know which datastore you are using? And For indexing are you SOLR or ES?

Comment: I'm not using any indexing at the moment so no SOLR or ES. I'm currently not interested in any datastore, instead I would prefer to just have a list of files (file for each url result)

Comment: Why don't you consider using Crawler4j? https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j

Comment: @RamachandraReddy this is the first time I encountered it. How well can it handle loads? I will need to crawl about 2M URLs in about a day or two? how reliable is it?

Comment: I too had the similar requirement. I have tried 100K, and it worked perfect, and also it will take couple of hours to get started.

Comment: Did you need to distribute it on several machines? Or 1 machine was sufficient?

Comment: One machine is fine.

Comment: @RamachandraReddy I gave it a try but it seems to be terribly slow. I even posted another question about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405116/improving-performance-of-crawler4j)